# how to get underlying hostname for the machine where azure function app is running

Tags: c#, azure-functions

This code returns the web site name (`client-func-app.azurewebsites.net`) for an Azure Function app:

```
var hostName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME") ?? "NA";
```

Is there a way to get underlying machine (Windows/Linux) host name where functions are actually running?

For docker container this works,

```
var hostName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOSTNAME") ?? "NA";
```

but this is not working for underlying Azure Function app machine name.

Please suggest!

Comment: this works for me `var hostName = Environment.MachineName ?? "NA";`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple, it's just a C# way to get the windows machine name.

```
var hostName = Environment.MachineName ?? "NA";
```