# Get details of events picked by function instances

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I am deploying an azure function and scaled out to 2 instances using APSP. This function is a event trigger function and when I publish the events the function instances are processing those but, in Insights i cant able to find which event is processed by which instance.

Tried to filter out the insights using HostInstanceId, prod_InstanceId, cloud role instance but, not able to fetch the desired results.

Is there any query OR filter that can bring these details from insights?

Comment: What is *APSP*?

Comment: Do you mean the HostInstanceId, prod_InstanceId and cloud role instance are always the same when you say that you are not able to fetch the desired results?

Comment: I think OP meant App Service Plan by APSP. Or App service plan - Premium.

Comment: APSP - App service plan. Suppose there 10 events published to process and each instance processed 5. Then how am able to check the logs in AI? I want check the logs for the events which are processed by instance2.

Comment: While your event handler code executes, you could emit log info with hostname of the instance, that way you can see in App Insights logs. There is no out of the box way to see the node name. Having said that, Azure will scale and instances will come and go, so, why do you want to know _which_ node handled your event - that is not necessary IMO.

Comment: If you are using C#, this `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()` will get you the host name of the instance.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

These are the results we will get to identify the which instance executed the current run or previous run history with the help of `HostInstanceId`

As @AnandSowmithiran suggested the code bit to get the host name, it is working on locally (getting my machine name) and in the Azure:

```cs
 string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
 string responseMessage = $"Hello Pravallika, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully and the host name is {hostName}";
```

[image]

If you try with the variables `WEBSITE_HOSTNAME` or `WEBSITE_SITE_NAME`, you’ll be getting the Azure Function configured Domain Site URL or Server Name which is given in this SO Refs [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73407247/how-to-get-underlying-hostname-for-the-machine-where-azure-function-app-is-runni) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586433/how-to-get-the-hostname-for-where-the-azure-function-run-from-timer-trigger).